# Powershell read XML value

Tags: xml, powershell

I have the following XML, and I'm trying to obtain the value where the `Name` attribute is `ComponentVersion`.

```
<Component .......>
  <Settings>
    <Setting Name="ComponentVersion" Value="12345" />
    <Setting Name="Host" Value="false" />
  </Settings>
  <Jobs>
    <Job Name="Platform" />
  </Jobs>
</Component>
```

I read the XML file like this:

```
$fullPathXML = "$env:PackagesPath\Platform\Components\SystemPlatform.Comp.xml"
[xml]$xmlSystemPlatform = Get-Content $fullPathXML
```

and then tried the following:

1. `$xmlSystemPlatform.selectNodes('//Settings/Setting') | select Name`
2. `Select-Xml '//Settings/Setting[contains(@Name, "ComponentVersion")]' $xmlSystemPlatform  |%{$_.Node.Value}`
3. `$xmlSystemPlatform.Settings.Setting[0].Name`
   `$xmlSystemPlatform.Settings.Setting[0].Value`

Answer (score 2):

```
$xmlSystemPlatform.Component.Settings.Setting | ? Name -eq "ComponentVersion" | select Value
```

Comment: Note that the simplified filter syntax requires PowerShell v3 or newer. For earlier versions you need `? { $_.Name -eq "ComponentVersion" }`.

Answer (score 1):

Using an [XPath expression](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/saxon6.5.3/expressions.html) something like this should work:

```psh
$filename = "$env:PackagesPath\Platform\Components\SystemPlatform.Comp.xml"

[xml]$xml = Get-Content $filename

$xml.SelectNodes('//Settings/Setting[@Name = "ComponentVersion"]').Value
```

Note that XPath expressions are case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Another one-liner:

```
([Xml] (Get-Content "$env:PackagesPath\Platform\Components\SystemPlatform.Comp.xml")).SelectNodes("//Settings/Setting[@Name='ComponentVersion']").Value
```

Or if you prefer it with variable:

```
$xmlSystemPlatform.SelectNodes("//Settings/Setting[@Name='ComponentVersion']").Value
```